# How to measure the amount of calcium in a supplement?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

In chemistry lab, my group was assigned to determine the actual amount of calcium in a supplement.  We did this successfully using HCl to dissolve the tablet, vacuum filtration, and then the addition of sodium carbonate.  Next week, it has been suggested that we attempt it again using a different method.  Thus, we are seeking the most interesting way, albeit using elementary tools and chemicals, that one might do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the determination of calcium (at least) two methods are conceivable:

- **gravimetric analysis**
  Sulfate is a rather bad choice here. As compared to the carbonate, the sulfate has a much higher solubility. A better choice would be the **oxalate** with a solubility around $6\,\mathrm{mg\,l^{-1}}$.
- **photometry**
  Calcium forms a purple complex with the [Arsenazo III dye](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/a92775) that can be detected at wavelengths of 660 and 700 nm.
  Alternatively, you can use [o-cresolphthalein](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/fluka/64000) and detect the complex at 545 nm.
- The photometric methods are typically used in automated high-throughput clinical analysis of calcium in serum, but given that a photometer isn't available in the students' lab, *Karl*'s comment on EDTA is exactly what you might be looking for. **Complexometric titration** is the keyword you might want to look for. Here, an indicator that forms a coloured complex with $\ce{Ca}$ is replaced by EDTA. The liberated indicator then shows a different colour.

Comment: Titration with EDTA?

Comment: @Karl Yes, that's definitely the classic. But there was a twist, wasn't it? $\ce{Mg}$ could be determined directly with Eriochrome Black T as the indicator, while $\ce{Ca}$ was run in a repacement titration  because the binding to the indicator was somewhat sluggish.

Comment: I also remember something like that. But second semester is too long ago. I'd have to dig up Jander-Blasius  in my basement. ;-)

Comment: @Karl Same to me ;) You probably had the Merck broschure on complexometric titrations too :)

Comment: Right. Where'd you get your indoctrination?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47625/discussion-between-karl-and-klaus-warzecha).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the real problem about the experiment of complexometric titration was that you had a mixture of Mg/Ca (at least at my school). If you only have Ca present there should not be any twist to it.